# How intercept session get attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security, dropwizard

I was trying to implement persistence for sessions. I want to basically store the session data in a db and currently I'm using HttpSessionAttributeListener to store value in db when a new session is created.

I want to know how to retrieve the session from database ie how do I override the getSession attribute to retrieve from database.

Comment: Please update your question with your configuration and what you have tried so far. With that, it'd be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass a parameter of type HttpSession to your controller.

Then access it using :

```
session.getAttribut(atr)
```

And modify it using

```
session.setAttribut(atr,"value")
```